# "SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch" even when my Key and CRT match

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509certificate, pki

I just generated a new CSR and key for my server and I can't seem to get this working. This isn't the first time I have rekeyed.. I get when running `sudo nginx -t`:

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/home/ubuntu/code/www/ssl/xxxxxxx.xxx.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I have tried :

```
openssl x509 -in /path/to/yourdomain.crt -noout -modulus | openssl sha1
openssl rsa -in /path/to/your.key -noout -modulus | openssl sha1
```

And: https://decoder.link/matcher/

And they both indicate a match. What else could be the issue?

Note: I have also checked if my CRT and CSR are valid through the GoDaddy SSL Tools.

Comment: If the moduli are equal what you have is the public key, not the private key. The certificate cannot possibly be used to produce the modulus of the private key.

Comment: Interesting.. So here is what I was following to produce that: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9781/2238/nginx-ssl-error0b080074x509-certificate-routines-x509checkprivatekeykey-values-mismatch 

I am using the key that was produce when I created the CSR. Is there something I am missing to produce a private key? @MarquisofLorne

Comment: The private key was the first thing you produced, and the CSR the second. The documentation for `openssl rsa -modulus` clearly states that it produces the modulus of the *public* key.

Comment: Okay so I generated my CSR without the key following something like this : https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/security/ssl/generating-a-private-key-and-csr-from-the-command-line. It provides a key and csr. Would you be familiar with this method? @MarquisofLorne

Comment: @MarquisofLorne: The modulus of the public key and the private key *are* the same for a matched keypair.

Comment: Thank you. I will rekey and create a CSR based off of a private key. Should do the trick

Comment: The public exponents also have to match, though almost everybody uses 65537 these days so that's not usually the issue. We have no way of knowing what it is really in your config file though. You might look at #2 in that support article.